# Ruby on Rails hosting - Engineyard vs Enterprise-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting, engineyard

I've been running a Rails app on 1 big dedicated server. Now for scaling I want to switch to a cloud service hoster and serve the app on 3 instances - App, DB and Redis.

I have really bad experience with Heroku performance wise and hence cost efficiency. So for me 2 Alternatives remain: Engineyard and Enterprise-Rails.

What I find important is that Engineyard doesn't offer an autoscaling option to handle peaks. On the other hand Enterprise-Rails doesn't have too much of documentation, most of it is handled by a support crew which is setting up everything.

What are other differences and what should I use for my website? I don't need much of administration work and I am not experienced with it. Basically I just want my Site to run optimally safe, stable and cost efficient without much personal work involved.

Answer (score 3):

I am running a massive Rails app off AWS at this time and I'm really happy with it. Previously I had a number of dedicated boxes that were always causing problems - sooner or later one of them would crash for some reason, Raid failures, database problems whatnot.

At AWS I use RDS for database, elastic cache for caching, I keep all my code on a fat instance that acts as staging server and get a variable number of reserved instances to load the code via NFS.

I also use autoscaling - we've prepaid for a number of reserved instances and autoscaling helps starting up nodes when CPU usage goes above 60%, then removing them when it goes below 25%. autoscaling rules are based on cloudwatch alerts that can be set to monitor a particular group of instances, memcache servers, and so on, you even get e-mails and SMS notifications via SNS when certain scaling activities take place, say when more than 100 instances are spammed in less than 1 hour (massive traffic spike). The instances also get added right up to the load balancers by the way and you don't need to mess with the session store as you can use the sticky session feature which is quite nice.

Recently I also started using a 2nd launch group with spot instances, this complicated things a bit in terms of cloudwatch rules but I'm able to save a lot every month as spot prices are much lower. When the spot price (minimum) I bid is not enough, the set-up I have switches back to reserved instances.

Even more recently I've also started using CloudFront which got my app's page assets to load real fast (about 2 megs of CSS, JS, some icon sprites). Previously I was serving directly from instances via the load balancers.

This took about 20 hours to deploy, test and tune for maximum performance and availability.

One of the problems I have with AWS is that there's no support unless you're prepared to foot a bill. They claim *some* support is offered without a subscription but the only option in the support area is Billing. Ha. Fortunately it's all stable enough not to put me in a position where I'd have to pay for it.

Overall Rails fits in quite nice with AWS. I spend less than 2 hours per month doing maintenance, where I was spending over 30 previously. Most important for me is that I know that I can GTFO on a vacation for X months knowing nothing will cause any trouble - haven't had a monitoring alert more than a year.

Later edit: the app is a sports site with white labeling feature, lots of users, lots of administrators working on content in the back-end, database intensive as we show market pricing data that should update every few seconds. I had an average load time of about 3 seconds per page with dedicated servers that were doing about the same thing - database, memcache, storage, load balancing, web app. Now my average is under 1 second. Monthly bill is about 8 times lower now.

Comment: The thing with AWS though is, that it is a IaaS which just offer the system to build my app. Heroku/Engineyard/Enterprise-Rails/anynines is a PaaS which does not need much setup or maintenance work. And I'd prefer a PaaS as I rather develop my app, than maintaining the system. So I need something that is easy to scale and set up.

Comment: True, you have to spend some hours setting it up initially. Maybe there are some AMIs on the marketplace with full RoR stacks though, these might save a few hours of work.

Answer (score -1):

While Engine Yard doesn't offer auto-scaling (it is in the pipeline), we do have a fairly easy to use scaling feature that allows you to spin up multiple instances at once in times of need.

The advantages over something like Enterprise-Rails is the full documentation, the choice to deploy from the CLI or the dashboard,and our amazing support team.  It's also easier to use Engine Yard and move from a personal machine or from another cloud setup than it is using a service such as AWS directly.